# Localizing elements in Azure AD B2C for password reset policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to localize elements associated with api.localaccountpasswordreset. I had no problem setting up localization for api.signuporsignin, so I followed the same [process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

I can't get the content to update for the Send verification code/Verify code/Send new code buttons or any of the validation messages. Here is what i'm trying:

```
 <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset.en">
    <LocalizedStrings>
    <!-- error messages - 2 attempts for same element -->
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="success_send_code_msg">testing -- Verification code has been sent to your inbox. Please copy it to the input box below.</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="ver_info_msg">testing -- Verification code has been sent to your inbox. Please copy it to the input box below.</LocalizedString>
    <!-- buttons -->
      <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_verify_code">testing -- Verify code</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="ver_but_send">testing -- Send verification code</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>
  </LocalizedResources>
```

Would appreciate the help if anyone has encountered this before! Thanks

Comment: Are you using a displayControl for email verification? Or the verified.Email output claim?

Comment: We are using a displayControl.

Comment: Would be nice to have the complete extension file. Are you adding the references to the ContentDefinition?